# Send email using apex and use office365 email address

Tags: apex, email

I am sending an email through apex using a Vf template. Everything works great, but the email sent is via xxxcwhehqjsf.466ou.55-xq7eae.cs41.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com and which sometimes gets flagged to spam.

Is there a way we can send the email using the logged in users email address which is a office365 account. I have already linked SF to use office365. But it doesnt use the office365 account while sending from apex.

Any thoughts on how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

This address is a feature of Email Bounce Management (see this [help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=5)). You may also want to read about [Improving Deliverability of Emails from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_send_from_salesforce_improve_deliverability.htm&type=5). You can "get rid" of this weird address by disabling Bounce Management, but that won't necessarily stop the mail from going to spam. You can improve deliverability by setting up DKIM (Domain Keys Identified Mail), SPF (Sender Policy Framework) record, and/or an [Email Relay](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&type=5) through your own mail servers. I apologize for the links, but there's really a lot more than I could copy-paste here, and the documentation is actually quite adequate in this case, so I suggest you start with the above links.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. i knew i wouldn't be simple one :)